# Why did this .tar.gz fail to install?

Tags: compiling

When I did the configure, I got this output

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
```

Comment: Please show your input as well as your output. Ideally, if possible, tell us *what* you are installing.

Comment: `checking for ???... no` you don't seem to have any C/C++ compiler installed.

Comment: You don't have a C++ compiler installed. Install one with `sudo apt-get install build-essential` and run `configure` again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Answer (score 1):

Below command should help you out. If not, please post your input and output as well.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc*
```

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum, when compiling software from source, have the `build-essential` package installed:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

It will install `g++`, `make` and Debian package development tools.